# Mysql query not working with python script

Tags: python, mysql

I know, 'not working' is pretty vague, but that is what's happening with this script.

I have a database with table `_added_points` that looks like this.

```
    id  g_id  g_name                       by_score  by_rank  by_percentage
------  ----  ---------------------------  --------  -------  -------------
     1  2332  john-doedd                        307      408         (NULL)
     2  3724  maxx                              844       15         (NULL)
     3  5208  orion-straxee-asset               663      122         (NULL)
     4  8333  Proton                            777       49         (NULL)
     5  9029  contax-dgaaevel                   155      542         (NULL)
     6  6789  clanstrom-e                       803       32         (NULL)
     7  1250  rexx-bundle                       666      119         (NULL)
     8  0236  cluster-performance-toolkit       154      543         (NULL)
     9  0334  gotas                             493      263         (NULL)
    10  3470  pleximoir                         611      163         (NULL)
```

Using the below, mysql code, I am trying to give a `percentage` to each user buy calculating the `by_score` field.

```
SET @total= (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM _added_points);
SELECT s1.g_name, s1.g_id, FLOOR(nge / @total * 100) + 1 AS percent 
FROM _added_points s1
JOIN (SELECT s1.id, COUNT(s2.id) AS nge
    FROM _added_points s1
    JOIN _added_points s2
    ON s1.by_score <= s2.by_score
    GROUP BY s1.id) AS s2
ON s1.id = s2.id
ORDER BY by_score DESC
```

The problem with the above script is, that it works when I run it using a a query builder of Mysql Workbench or SQLyog .. but when I run it with a python script, the I get nothing. Something like this:

```
[root@localhost crawler]# python _added_points.py
()
```

I have more than double checked if there was an issue with my python code, but there is nothing. Even the `try`: `except` block can't catch any exception.

Is there a code that works on mysql clients, but not when run as on programs like python, or php? It does not seem logical, but that is exactly what is happening.

Comment: You should also post your Python code.

Comment: @Selcuk I knew someone would say that, there is nothing except a mysql query. that works with other query, but NOT with this one.

Comment: Can python mysql library handle 2 queries at the same time?

Comment: @Mihai That would be the only case which would make sense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try executing two queries, the first to set the user-defined variable and the second query which references the variable:

```
cursor.execute('SET @total= (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM _added_points)')
cursor.execute('''SELECT s1.g_name, s1.g_id, FLOOR(nge / @total * 100) + 1 AS percent 
FROM _added_points s1
JOIN (SELECT s1.id, COUNT(s2.id) AS nge
    FROM _added_points s1
    JOIN _added_points s2
    ON s1.by_score <= s2.by_score
    GROUP BY s1.id) AS s2
ON s1.id = s2.id
ORDER BY by_score DESC''')
```

Comment: after hours of trying everything, this only worked for me. Even though it looks like a big hack, I have no choice but to accept it. Thanks!!

Comment: I think that it has to be done this way in order for the user-defined variable to be present in the session. It's not such a big hack though, not all DB-API interfaces support execution of multiple SQL queries - `sqlite3` for example.